# CSS grid - create checkboard like grid where the last item is not of the same size and is pushed to the last column

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create the grid where I would create a checkboard like grid where all items would be of the same size, but the last one. The last item should be pushed all the way to the last column. 
It would look like this:

[image]

I am creating the grid like this:

```
  grid: {
    display: 'grid',
    gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(auto-fill, 8rem)',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
```

But, I am not sure how can I set the last item to take up the last two columns no matter what is the number of the items in the grid, so that it always takes the space in the right corner of the grid, or to create a new row for a button where it would sit in the right corner. The problem is that the number of items is dynamic so I don't know the width of the container, otherwise it would be easy to position the button under this grid.

Comment: Are you talking about the button? But if it's not the same size, it can't be done.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the button. Was looking to see if there is any solution for this.

Comment: Not as a direct grid-element. You could wrap it a div and possibly move *that* to the last column/row. Not everything *has* to be in the grid.

Comment: I found a solution with setting the grid columns to ```gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(auto-fit, minmax(8rem, 1.25fr))',```. That way the grid takes up the 100% of the container and then I can align the button inside of the container to the right corner.

Comment: 1fr was fine too ;) (mind removing the justify-content too) , i misunderstood the question, i thought the button to the right was the priority